# Create a div that acts like an html checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to turn on/off the div on click (it should act like an html checkbox) and make visible changes using css. Is this possible without Javascript, or would I have to use Javascript?

If you have created such a script please share it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It isn't possible without JavaScript (unless you would send every click as a link to the server and use php to modify the div - which I hope you're don't want to do). I wouldn't recommend doing this unless you really can't do it with checkboxes because it will make the site unusable for people without JavaScript enabled.

Comment: Actually you can *almost* do this by positioning a real checkbox over another element and giving it 0% opacity, and a height and width as necessary. However making something visual happen based on the checkbox state would rely on browser support for the ":checked" pseudo-class, which I think remains limited.

Answer (score 23):

You could do this very easily with only CSS code by hiding the checkboxes and styling their labels like so: 
HTML

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" checked="checked" />
    <label class="whatever" for="r1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="2" id="r2" />
    <label class="whatever" for="r2"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="3" id="r3" />
    <label class="whatever" for="r3"></label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.whatever{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
}

#checkboxes input[type=checkbox]:checked + .whatever{
    background-color: green;
}
```

You can take a look at this simple code in action here: 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicosemp/c3n12ey3/7/) 
Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This looks great, thanks for making it! What is the role of the  `#checkboxes` code? The fiddle works just the same without it.

Comment: It just increases specificity. If you only use `input[type=checkbox]` in the CSS, you will apply the rule to any checkbox on the page. By using `#checkboxes` you only apply it to checkboxes that are in a `div` with `id="checkboxes"`.

Comment: This was exactly I was looking for. Fits well into my react component!

Comment: simple and best :)

Answer (score 5):

You could implement this without javascript by using the label element to wrap the div you want clickable:

```
<input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox1">
   Click me
</label>
```

and css:

```
input {
  display:none;
}
:checked + label {
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

see here for an example with css styling http://jsfiddle.net/vyP7c/761/

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to answer your question and I have created a little jQuery(1.5.2) code.
Hope this would help just have a look and tell me is this what you are looking for?, or if you want something else I can made it too. In this script on clicking a `div` element with id `on_off` (You can select it too by using var!) and class for on (`on_off_on`) and off (`on_off_off`) and by the way you can select them too, just get to this jsFiddle link for
[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/qCnyM/) or you can see the script below --

HTML --

```
<html>
     <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" ></script>
     </head>
     <body>
           <div id="on_off" class="on_off_on" >ON</div>
     </body>
</html>
```

CSS --

```
div.on_off_off
{
 background: rgb(150,110,120);
 font-family: segoe ui;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 3px solid rgb(180, 140, 150);
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
}
div.on_off_on
{
 background: rgb(110,150,120);
 font-family: segoe ui;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 3px solid rgb(140, 180, 150);
 border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 display: inline;
}
```

jQuery Code --

```
$(document.body).ready(function () {
    $(function () {

      var main_obj_id = 'on_off';
      var on_class = 'on_off_on';
      var off_class = 'on_off_off';        

        $('#' + main_obj_id).click(function () {
              if ($(this).is('.' + on_class)) {

                 $(this).removeClass(on_class);
                 $(this).addClass(off_class);
                 $(this).html('OFF');

              } else {

                 $(this).removeClass(off_class);
                 $(this).addClass(on_class);
                 $(this).html('ON');                  

              }
        });
    });
});
```

Hope this would help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to use javascript and it is prety simple. You just need to change css style of div on action.

```
<a href='javascript: toggle()'>toggle</a>
<div id='div1' style='display:none'>
Don't display me
</div>

<script>
function toggle(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1')
    if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
        div1.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        div1.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
</script>
```