# How do i use pseudo elements to change which class is getting a style?

Tags: html, css

[I have this navbar currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQOoZ.png)

[I am trying to make it so that whenever you click on one of the navbar elements this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsQpu.png)

The navbar html:

```
    <div class="navbar-container">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="text-radius home-radius">
                <p><a href="#" class="nav-anchor">Home</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-radius profile-radius">
                <p><a href="#profile" class="nav-anchor">Profile</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="text-radius contact-radius">
                <p><a href="#contact" class="nav-anchor">Contact</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The navbar css:

```
.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.navbar-wrapper {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    border-radius: 5em;
    background-color: var(--lightgrey);
    width: 18.8em;
    height: 3em;
    
}

.nav-anchor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--black);
    
}

.text-radius {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 5.8em;
    height: 2.5em;
    border-radius: 5em;
}

.home-radius:active {
    background-color: var(--white);
}

.profile-radius:active {
    background-color: var(--white);
}

.contact-radius:active {
    background-color: var(--white);
}
```

What i've tried:

- I've tried to use :active, :focus & :target, and they do not seem to work. I am puzzled now.

I AM TRYING TO DO THIS WITHOUT JS BY THE WAY.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

If you need to remain focus when clicking somewhere else, [using a hidden check box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523213/create-a-div-that-acts-like-an-html-checkbox) can do the job. Since you only want to focus on one, you can change it to radius boxes.

```css
.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.navbar-wrapper {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    border-radius: 5em;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 18.8em;
    height: 3em;
    
}

.nav-anchor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}

.text-radius {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 5.8em;
    height: 2.5em;
    border-radius: 5em;
}

.home-radius:focus-within{
    background-color: white;
}

.profile-radius:focus-within{
    background-color: white;
}

.contact-radius:focus-within{
    background-color: white;
}

.navbar-wrapper input[type=radio]{
    display: none;
}

.navbar-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked + .text-radius{
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" checked="checked">
        <label class="text-radius contact-radius nav-anchor" for="r1" onclick='window.location.assign("#")'> Home </label>
        <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="2" id="r2">
        <label class="text-radius contact-radius nav-anchor" for="r2" onclick='window.location.assign("#Profile")'>Profile</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="3" id="r3">
        <label class="text-radius contact-radius nav-anchor" for="r3" onclick='window.location.assign("#Contact")'>Contact</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

To make a div focusable, you can add `tabindex` onto it, and use the `focus` selector. Note that in your structure, clicking on `<a>` will not focus on the div, to solve this you can use the `focus-within` selector:

```css
.navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.navbar-wrapper {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 5px;
    border-radius: 5em;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width: 18.8em;
    height: 3em;
    
}

.nav-anchor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    
}

.text-radius {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 5.8em;
    height: 2.5em;
    border-radius: 5em;
}

.home-radius:focus-within{
    background-color: white;
}

.profile-radius:focus-within{
    background-color: white;
}

.contact-radius:focus-within{
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="text-radius home-radius" tabindex="0">
            <p><a href="#" class="nav-anchor">Home</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-radius profile-radius" tabindex="1">
            <p><a href="#profile" class="nav-anchor">Profile</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-radius contact-radius" tabindex="2">
            <p><a href="#contact" class="nav-anchor">Contact</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done this now, but whenever i click somewhere else on the webpage it removes the focus, is it possible to do it so it focuses only in the navbar? So whenever i click somewhere else itll still stay and only when i click in the navbar itll change the focus there.

Comment: hmm only thing I can think of is using a hidden checkbox, something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523213/create-a-div-that-acts-like-an-html-checkbox